# Android application force close without any error shown

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android application using `Eclipse` as IDE, when I got a force close error on the emulator and on my phone.
I just changed the layout and the `strings.xml` and I have no errors shown in eclipse, still it says "force close" when I try to open the application on the eclipse emulator or smartphone.
This is my layout , main.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ButtonConnect" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/device"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/connect"
    android:text="@string/ButtonDevice" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/joystick_hulle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/joystickhulle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/joystick_bg" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/joystick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/joystick"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/joystick_hulle"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/joystick_hulle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:src="@drawable/joystick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M1P"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/device"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/device"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilhoch" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M2P"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M1P"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M1P"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/M1P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilhoch" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M3P"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M2P"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M2P"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/M2P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilhoch" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M4P"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M3P"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M3P"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/M3P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilhoch" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M1N"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/M1P"
    android:layout_below="@+id/M1P"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilrunter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M2N"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M1N"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M1N"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/M3P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilrunter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M5P"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/M1N"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/M4P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilhoch" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M5N"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M2N"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M2N"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/M5P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilrunter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M4N"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M5N"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M5N"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/M5P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilrunter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/M3N"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M2N"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M2N"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/M3P"
    android:text="@string/Pfeilrunter" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/M1T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/M1P"
    android:layout_below="@+id/M1P"
    android:text="@string/Motor1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/M2T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M1T"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M1T"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/M3P"
    android:text="@string/Motor2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/M3T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M2T"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M2T"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/M3P"
    android:text="@string/Motor3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/M4T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M3T"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M3T"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/M4P"
    android:text="@string/Motor4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/M5T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/M4T"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/M4T"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/M5P"
    android:text="@string/Motor5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope you can help me.

EDIT: here is the logcat(just copied the errors):

```
10-29 13:10:20.245: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
10-29 13:10:29.735: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
10-29 13:10:31.146: E/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
10-29 13:10:31.146: E/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
10-29 13:10:31.146: E/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
10-29 13:10:31.175: E/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
10-29 13:10:37.396: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
10-29 13:10:37.396: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
10-29 13:10:38.207: E/System(58): Failure starting core service
10-29 13:10:38.207: E/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
10-29 13:10:38.207: E/System(58):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
10-29 13:10:38.207: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
10-29 13:10:38.207: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
10-29 13:10:38.207: E/System(58):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
10-29 13:10:39.256: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-29 13:10:39.266: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-29 13:10:39.266: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-29 13:10:39.276: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-29 13:10:39.286: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-29 13:10:41.646: E/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
10-29 13:10:42.796: E/logwrapper(143): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
10-29 13:10:42.936: E/logwrapper(145): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
10-29 13:10:42.956: E/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
10-29 13:10:52.650: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{android.androcrane.htlottakring/android.androcrane.htlottakring.Androcrane}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.androcrane.htlottakring.Androcrane in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/android.androcrane.htlottakring-2.apk]
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.androcrane.htlottakring.Androcrane in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/android.androcrane.htlottakring-2.apk]
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  ... 11 more
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: You can see exception at `logcat` output.

Comment: In Eclipse, open the Logcat view, in order to view the exception's stack. Then paste the stack here.

Comment: try after `Cleaning` your project.

Comment: `10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.androcrane.htlottakring.Androcrane in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/android.androcrane.htlottakring-2.apk]`
this is the error causing the crash, sometimes it's due to errors while building project and building it again is enough to fix it.

Comment: Hmm thanks, do you know how i could fix that?

Comment: in Project Properties, make sure that your source folders are included in Java Build Path

Comment: It says that in my source folder everything is included.

Comment: Remember that the `android:orientation` attribute is unnecessary (and not valid) in RelativeLayout.

Comment: can you try to run on new avd device may be the cause was the device files is corrupted

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have occured because there's a missing class in corresponding location

heres an excerpt from your log

```
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.androcrane.htlottakring.Androcrane in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/android.androcrane.htlottakring-2.apk]
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-29 13:11:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  ... 11 more
```

so make sure this class is located there.to avoid this

Answer (score -1):

It couldbe an error with your Relative Layout, sometimes the order of the element in the xml is important and can cause crash.
Erase you layout and recreate all the components with the design mode.

Comment: Cleaning or restarting didnt really work.
I am new to eclipse so i dont know how to use the design mode, so i thought after LinearLayout, the RelativeLayout would be better because i could move the buttons better.

Comment: Yeah, Relative Layout can be better, depending on the situation. But I have experienced some problems when I tried to add an ImageView at the bottom of the xml file which is displayed at the top of the screen. But according to your logcat I'm not sure my solution is the good one for you.

Comment: Just saying it's caused by a RelativeLayout without evidence ain't cool. Or do you have a specific reason why you think it's caused by the Layout? I can't see anything in the logcat which supports your answer.

Comment: I have seen this multiple time in my application when a change of the order of declaration in the xml layout of the views in a relative layout can make the application crash when it tries to inflate the view.